# Not able to read <strong> tag using NSHTMLTextDocumentType

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring

My code is not able to read `<strong>` tag and I am not able to make it Bold:

```
let txt = "`<p><em>The first day of your <strong>Kerala tour itinerary</strong> starts with a trip along the winding roads to the beautiful hill station of Munnar</em></p>\r\n<p>`Your holiday to the mesmerizing Munnar starts with `a&nbsp;`transfer from Cochin. Enjoy the picturesque hill-station as you drive through the serpentine roads surrounded by lush green hills. En route, visit the beautiful Cheeyappara, Valara, and Attukadu waterfalls and the spice plantations, as part of your `<strong>3 day Kerala tourism package itinerary</strong>.` Upon arrival, check-in to the hotel and relax for a while. Later, enjoy local sightseeing and marvel at the beauty all around. Mark an end to the first day of `<strong>Munnar tour package</strong>` with a comfortable overnight stay at the hotel.`&nbsp;</p>\r\n<p><strong>Distance from Cochin to Munnar:</strong>&nbsp;130 km (approx.)<br /><strong>Travel Time:</strong>&nbsp;4 hours (approx.)&nbsp;</p>`"




let dataValue = txt.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode,
                         allowLossyConversion: true)!
let optionaArr = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType]

let attrStr = try! NSAttributedString(data: dataValue,
                                       options: optionaArr,
                                       documentAttributes: nil)      
txtView.attributedText = attrStr
```

Other than  tag I can able to read all tags like `<p>, <em>` and all. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The below code works for me (swift 4.1 & Xcode 9.3)

```
let txt = "`<p><em>The first day of your <strong>Kerala tour itinerary</strong> starts with a trip along the winding roads to the beautiful hill station of Munnar</em></p>\r\n<p>`Your holiday to the mesmerizing Munnar starts with `a&nbsp;`transfer from Cochin. Enjoy the picturesque hill-station as you drive through the serpentine roads surrounded by lush green hills. En route, visit the beautiful Cheeyappara, Valara, and Attukadu waterfalls and the spice plantations, as part of your `<strong>3 day Kerala tourism package itinerary</strong>.` Upon arrival, check-in to the hotel and relax for a while. Later, enjoy local sightseeing and marvel at the beauty all around. Mark an end to the first day of `<strong>Munnar tour package</strong>` with a comfortable overnight stay at the hotel.`&nbsp;</p>\r\n<p><strong>Distance from Cochin to Munnar:</strong>&nbsp;130 km (approx.)<br /><strong>Travel Time:</strong>&nbsp;4 hours (approx.)&nbsp;</p>`"

let dataValue = txt.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode,
                         allowLossyConversion: true)!

let attrStr = try! NSAttributedString(data: dataValue,
                       options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html],
                       documentAttributes: nil)
txtView.attributedText = attrStr
```

### Simulator Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Hi Inder, thanks for this reply, but I am using swift 3.2, I am sorry for not mentioning before. Can you post this answer for Swift 3.2. Really appreciate your help...

Comment: Hi kulss, I don't have old xcode so cant do much about it sorry.

Comment: Oh! , My tuff luck, Well thanks for this answer, I am going update my code to Swift 4.0